# How to plot graph using plot function inside a function using if loop in R

Tags: r

```
crime.value = 1

crime.bar <- function() {
  bp<-ggplot(df_category, aes(x=Category, y=Frequency, fill=Category)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
  bp
}

  if (crime.value == 1) {
    crime.bar()
  }
```

The Plot function works when i call `crime.bar()` seperately. but when called through a if loop it doesn't work. please help.

Comment: You need to use `print(bp)` within the loop to force the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `print(bp)` within the loop to force the output. Thanks to @Dave2e